# Shimano MTB levers with Shimano flat mount road disk brakes (hydraulic)

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, compatibility

Can you use Shimano MTB levers with Shimano flat mount road disk brakes (hydraulic)? Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Shimano XT (mountain) hydraulic disc brake caliper be used with an Ultegra STI road brake lever?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57794/can-a-shimano-xt-mountain-hydraulic-disc-brake-caliper-be-used-with-an-ultegra)

Comment: VTLO because the suggested duplicate is the opposite way around, asking about hydraulic brifters and MTB calipers.  Still relevant, just flipped.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can do that. Just make sure you use a new olive and insert pin.

I have seen it done on a self build frame of a guy as the wanted to integrate the brake as much as possible in the rear. You can follow the link and use and use a translator as it is in german.

https://www.mtb-news.de/news/2018/12/20/bike-der-woche-suit-1-eigenbau/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect so, but haven't done it myself.  Reason - brake calipers have about the same amount of movement.  Rotors are about the same thickness.  The only difference would be the overall rotor diameter is likely to be smaller for a road bike with 160mm being large, 140mm being small.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but basing it purely on level and piston travel is dangerous, since that assumes that the diameter of the pistons moving the oil are the same between brake lever and piston. Incidentally, the Shimano's pistons are standardized (22 mm diameter, except for the 4-piston designs), as far as I have read.